# Delphi TRestrequest resulting in a 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: rest, delphi, unauthorized

I'm trying to call API to post a zip-file using the Delphi `TRestRequest`-components.
If I use Postman, I get the expected result. However if I'm using `TRestRequest` I'm getting an `401 Unauthorized` error.

In Postman my request look like this:

> POST https://docs.ixor.be/api/upload
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data
> Access-Token: <token>
>
> form-data:
> data: (file) documents.zip
> type: documents
> reference: testref

In Delphi, my code looks like this

```
SendFile := TMemoryStream.Create;
SendFile.LoadFromFile(bestand);
SendFile.Position := 0;
RESTClientIxor.BaseURL := 'https://docs.ixor.be/api/upload';
RESTRequestIxor.Params.Clear;
RESTRequestIxor.Params.AddItem('Access-token', '<token>', pkHTTPHEADER, [], ctNone);
RESTRequestIxor.Params.AddItem('Content-type','multipart/form-data', pkHTTPHEADER, [], ctNone);
RESTRequestIxor.Params.AddItem('reference', QFactuurproacc.AsString, pkREQUESTBODY, [], ctMULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
RESTRequestIxor.Params.AddItem('type', 'documents', pkREQUESTBODY, [],ctMULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
RESTRequestIxor.Params.AddItem('data', SendFile, pkFILE, [], ctMULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
RestRequestIxor.Method := rmPOST;
RESTRequestIxor.Execute;
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are several things you do wrong: **1.** Don't specify `Content-Type` header to let `TRESTClient` generate the header value for you. **2.** Use proper content type for individual body parts - `ctNone` or `ctTEXT_PLAIN` for `'reference'` and `'type'`; `ctAPPLICATION_ZIP` for `'data'`. **3.** Prefer shorthand methods `AddBody` and `AddFile` over `Params.AddItem`; it makes your code shorter more expressive. **4.** `pkFILE` expects path to a file (not content) in parameter value. I'm surprised that your code doesn't crash on this. **5.** You don't free the stream.

Comment: However, you're getting `401 Unauthorized`, which could point to a real problem - the access token is invalid or expired.

Comment: Adjustment: starting from Delphi 10.3 it is possible to use `pkFILE` with a stream. But why would you do that in your use case. If you insist on using the stream then consider `TFileStream` in place of `TMemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, try adding the authentication parameter (token) through the method "RESTClientIxor.AddAuthParameter" or "RESTRequestIxor.AddAuthParameter" to solve the authentication issue. This way, the component itself takes care of handling the parameter in the appropriate way.